# Is There a Threading module in Python Equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, python, python-multithreading

Is there a Threading module in Python equivalent in PHP? My code in Python would look something like

```
from Treading import thread

def somefunction():
    print("function")

t = Thread(target = somefunction)        
t.start()
```

Is there a way to convert code like this to PHP, if so, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Thread support in php is limited, then again threading in web apps has limited use - often a job queue system is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

There is. PHP has [`pthreads`](http://php.net/pthreads). As for how similar or how easy it is to convert your Python code using that, remains unclear.